# Android shake detection on emulator

Tags: android

I am pretty new to android. I have a use case where I need to detect a shake and show some images in my application. Can I test shake functionality on android emulator ? What are the other alternatives apart from testing it on a real phone ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is [Sensor Simulator](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator) http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator

Hope this helps